# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) - Android 11

Tags: java, android

I am not sure what I am doing wrong exactly but keep getting this error while trying to save the bitmap into a png file and send to another Activity:

```
private void savePhoto() {

    resolver = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "Image_" + ".jpg");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + getFilesDir() + File.separator + "TextPhoto");
    imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

    //            outputMediaFile.createNewFile();

    SaveSettings build = new SaveSettings.Builder().setClearViewsEnabled(true).setTransparencyEnabled(true).build();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == 0) {
        mPhotoEditor.saveAsFile(new File(imageUri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), build, new PhotoEditor.OnSaveListener() {
            public void onFailure(Exception exc) {
            }

            public void onSuccess(String str) {
                listPhoto.set(position, str);
                EditPhotoActivity editPhotoActivity = EditPhotoActivity.this;
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("AFTER", listPhoto);
                editPhotoActivity.setResult(115, editPhotoActivity.intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `keep getting this error` There is no error mentioned in your post nor the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: `File(imageUri.getPath()).` You cannot use the path part of a content scheme uri for the File class.

Comment: @blackapps I am getting blank image on next activity and got error:->  open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) this for android 11 device, on savePhoto() method.

Comment: There is no error mentioned in your post nor the stacktrace from logcat. Please write a decent post to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Content schema`content://` is not File schema `file://` cannot use in `File` class